# how to deploy a xgboost model on amazon sagemaker?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, xgboost, amazon-sagemaker

Is there a way to deploy a xgboost model trained locally using amazon sagemaker? I only saw tutorial talking about both training and deploying model with amazon sagemaker.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [example notebook](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/d5681a07611ae29567355b60b2f22500b561218b/advanced_functionality/xgboost_bring_your_own_model/xgboost_bring_your_own_model.ipynb) is good starting point showing how to use a pre-existing scikit-learn xgboost model with the Amazon SageMaker to create a hosted endpoint for that model.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted by [clicking the green check mark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpogP.png).